# Is it possible to obtain individual left and right image (or cvpixelbuffer) from iPhone dual camera

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation

AVFoundation uses the dual camera on some the recent "plus" iPhones to compute depth map. However, I am trying to obtain the individual left and right images as taken by the camera. I tried a few googling but there's nothing yet that either from apple development page, or people who have tried and posted as blog.

Note: I am not trying to get the depth map (which is a commonly known know-how), I would like the raw individual left and right images, and process the parallax info in some other ways.